# Add "Copy as suggestion" button to proposed suggestions in Traducir.win

Tags: feature-request, localization, traducir

Translation helper-proxy [Traducir](https://ru.traducir.win/) for Stack Exchange family sites has an ability to copy original (English) sentence as suggestion to edit area before reviewers can approve it. Can we add similar button to all already suggested sentences to simplify some small tuning if suggestion is good in general but can be improved?

> [image]

This won't require manual selecting and copy-n-paste suggested text to edit area.